Find the area of the region enclosed by $\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}=\frac{\sin x+\sin y}{\sin(x+y)}$ and the $x$-axis (comes from a probability question)
This question resisted attacks at MSE, so I am posting it here.

Here is the graph of $\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin y}=\dfrac{\sin x+\sin y}{\sin(x+y)}$.


Find the area of the region enclosed by the curve and the $x$-axis, from $x=0$ to $x=\pi$.

Context, and why I suspect the answer is $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$
This question arose when I asked myself: "A triangle's vertices are three uniformly random points on a circle. The side lengths are, in random order, $a,b,c$. The triangle inequality tells us that $P(a+b<c)=0$. But what is $P\left(a+b<\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)c\right)$, given that $\frac{a}{b}>1$ ?"
A simulation of $10^7$ random triangles yielded an estimated probability of $0.49998$, suggesting that the probability is $\frac12$, which would imply that the area in this question is $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$. The connection between the probability and the area is explained in the MSE question.
I decided to phrase this question in terms of area, but we can attack it in terms of area or probability.
Progress so far
I used Wolfram (changing $\sin y$ to $y$, and changing $\sin x$ to $a$) to help me change $\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}=\frac{\sin x+\sin y}{\sin(x+y)}$ to:
$$y=\arcsin\left(\frac13\left(\sin (2x)-\sin x+f(x)-\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right)\right)dx$$
where
$$f(x)=\left(\frac12\left(h(x)+\sqrt{4g(x)^3+h(x)^2}\right)\right)^\frac13$$
$$g(x)=3\sin^2 x-(\sin 2x-\sin x)^2$$
$$h(x)=-16\left(\cos x\right)\sin^5 x+10\left(\cos x\right)\sin^3x+24\sin^5 x+10\sin^3 x$$
In this answer at the MSE question, user @Masd reports that $\int_0^\pi y \, \mathrm dx$ matches $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$ to $11$ decimal places.
${}$

If you prefer to integrate something more explicit, it is (modulo some hand-waving that can, probably, be justified with some effort) the same as $\int_1^{1+\sqrt 2}\log\frac{t+1}{t(t-1)}\frac {dt}t$. Wolfram Alfa fails to reduce it to $\pi^2/8$, but claims that it is the same with as many digits as it can produce when asked to evaluate it numerically (80 or about that).

@fedja Mathematica evaluates this integral as $\frac{1}{4}\pi^2-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+\sqrt{2})^2+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-\sqrt{2})-\mathrm{Li}_2(\sqrt{2}-1)$. Combining this with (11) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.2170 (which has been published), we obtain that the integral equals $\pi^2/8$. I was led to Lima's paper by (19) at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html

@fedja Can you provide the details how to transform the original integral to your integral? With these details and Iosif Pinelis's answer, we will have a full answer.

@fedja I'm too are wondering how you arrived at your expression. In my attempt to settle the question, I derived the parametrization $(\cos x, \cos y)=(a(t), b(t))$ with $a(t)=(t^3+t^2+t-1)/(2t^2)$, $b(t)=(t^3+t^2-t+1)/(2t)$, where $\sqrt{2}-1\le t\le 1$. This yields that the area equals $\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1\frac{a'(t)}{\sqrt{1-a(t)^2}}\arccos b(t),dt$. But I don't see how to simplify that further or make use of that.

Continued: Using $\arccos b=\arctan\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}$, the integral representation of $\arctan$ and some minor computations, one obtains the double integral $\int_0^1(\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1\frac{a'(t)b(t)t}{b(t)^2(1-s^2)+s^2}dt)ds$. But that's probably a dead end.

@GHfromMO Done. Sorry for making you wait. I sort of hoped (and still hope) that someone would find a simple proof making all that stuff about $Li_2$ unnecessary, but since it hasn't come yet, I've posted my computation in the meantime.

Empirically, it seems that that the probability of $a+b<a/b\cdot c$ for different orderings of sides is $4/5$ if $a>c>b$ and $7/10$ if $c>a>b$. The inequality is certainly false if $a>b>c$, so the probability for the inequality holding if $a>b$ would indeed be $\frac13(4/5+7/10)=\frac12$ if these are correct.

Related claim: If the triangle's vertices are three uniformly random points on a sphere, the probability is $\frac{9}{25}$.

Related fact: The area enclosed by $\frac{\tan x}{\tan y}=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{\tan (x+y)}$ and the $y$-axis, from $y=0$ to $y=\frac{\pi}{2}$, is $\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}-3\ln^2 \phi\right)$. (Proof)

@PeterMueller Very nice reformulation! Can you share the details on how you arrived there? I assume you had $f(x,y)=0$ and then solved for either $x$ or $y$.. can the opposite be also done? (e.g. if you've solved for $x$ then what would the new integral look like if you solve for $y$).

Now regarding the integral you obtained, I'd use $\arccos x = 2\arctan \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$ to arrive at:
$$2\int_{\sqrt 2-1}^1 \frac{(x^3-x+2)\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}\frac{x^2+2x-1}{1+x^2}}}{x\sqrt{(1-x^4)(x^2+2x-1)}}dx$$$$\overset{\frac{1-x}{1+x}\to x}=2\int_0^{\sqrt 2-1}\int_0^{\sqrt x} \frac{x^3+5x^2+x+1}{(1-x^2)\sqrt x}\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2(1-2x-x^2)}dydx$$
We can invert the order of integration and since this is a rational function it should be doable. The problem is that it's not quite obvious how to simplify further, but I'm thinking that it's inverse can be easier  to deal with.

A related question: "Find the area of the region enclosed by $\sin^p x+\sin^p y=\sin^p(x+y)$, the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis."

A related question: "Is it true that in a triangle, if $a$ is the smallest side then $P\left(Rr > \frac{a^2}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$?"

Here is my computation. First of all, I had no idea whatsoever how to integrate implicit trigonometric functions, so I decided to switch to the integration with respect to the sides $x,y,z$ of the triangle $XYZ$. Recall that the conditions for the domain is $xz\le y^2+xy$, $x>y$ plus the triangle inequality $z>x-y$. This triangle inequality is compatible with the first condition if and only if $x< (\sqrt 2+1)y$. So the admissible domain is given by
$$
y< x< (\sqrt 2+1)y,\qquad x-y<z<y+\frac {y^2} x\,.
$$
Now we have to integrate over the points on the circle, i.e., for the case when the circumradius is $1$ and with respect to the angular variables. We relax the circumradius to $r>0$, place $Z$ on the positive semi-axis and the circle center at the origin (so $Z=r$), and take $Y=re^{2i\varphi}, X=re^{2i\psi}$, so
$$
x=2r\sin\varphi,\qquad y=2r\sin\psi,\qquad z=2r\sin(\varphi-\psi)
$$
(the last one up to a sign) where $\varphi,\psi$ run independently over $[0,\pi]$. The condition $x>y$ reduces the $d\varphi\,d\psi$ measure to $\frac{\pi^2}2$ and each admissible triple $x,y,z$ is realized twice (up to the flip about the horizontal axes). We can use any measure on $(0,+\infty)$ we want when integrating over $r$, so we will choose $\frac{dr}{r}$.
Now it is time to compute the Jacobian $J$ of the mapping $(r,\varphi,\psi)\mapsto (x,y,z)$. We have
$$
J=8\left|\begin{matrix}
\sin\varphi & r\cos\varphi & 0
\\
\sin\psi & 0 & r\cos\psi
\\
\sin(\varphi-\psi) &r\cos(\varphi-\psi) & -r\cos(\varphi-\psi)
\end{matrix}\right|
\\
=8r^2[\cos\varphi\cos\psi\sin(\varphi-\psi)-\sin\varphi\cos\psi\cos(\varphi-\psi)+\cos\varphi\sin\psi\cos(\varphi-\psi)]
\\
=8r^2[\cos\varphi\cos\psi\sin(\varphi-\psi)-
\sin(\varphi-\psi)\cos(\varphi-\psi)]
\\
=8r^2\sin(\varphi-\psi)\sin\varphi\sin\psi=\frac{xyz}r\,,
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{dr}r\,d\varphi\,d\psi=\frac{dx\,dy\,dz}{xyz}\,,
$$
which is pretty neat.
Now let $\Omega$ be the set of all good triangles and $\omega$ be the set of good triangles with $r=1$. Then the back of the envelope computation is the following:
$$
\left[\int_0^\infty\frac{dr}{r}\right]\int_\omega d\varphi\,d\psi=
2\int_{\Omega}\frac{dr}{r}\,d\varphi\,d\psi
=2\int_{\Omega}\frac{dx\,dy\,dz}{xyz}
\\
=
2\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{y}\left[\int_{y}^{(\sqrt 2+1)y}\frac{dx}x\left(\int_{x-y}^{y+\frac{y^2}x}\frac{dz}z\right)\right]
$$
Substituting $x=ty$, $t\in(1,\sqrt 2+1)$, we evaluate the inner integrals to
$$
\int_1^{\sqrt 2+1}\log\frac{t+1}{t(t-1)}\frac{dt}t\,,
$$
which is independent of $y$, so we finally get
$$2\left[\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}y\right]
\int_1^{\sqrt 2+1}\log\frac{t+1}{t(t-1)}\frac{dt}t\,,
$$
Now it remains to cancel $\int_0^\infty\frac{ds}s$ to get the claimed identity.
The little (but somewhat irritating) problem is that the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{ds}s$ diverges. However, as Landau (the physicist) used to say, "A chicken is not a bird and a logarithm is not infinity". So we will fix that with a little bit more elaborate argument. ${}{}$
We shall impose one extra condition on the admissible triangles, namely, we will demand that $y$ is comparable to $r$. We always trivially have $r\ge \frac y2$, so we'll fix a big $A>0$ and demand that $r<Ay$. Notice that it is a condition on the shape only, not on the size. Denoting by $\omega_A$ the set of admissible triangles with circumradius $1$ and by $\Omega_A$ the set of all admissible triangles and choosing a huge finite $R>0$, we can write, as before,
$$
\left[\int_1^R\frac{dr}r\right]\int_{\omega_A}d\varphi\,d\psi=2\int_{\Omega_A\cap\{1<r<R\}}\frac{dx\,dy\,dz}{xyz}\,.
$$
Now notice that
$$
\Omega_A\cap\{2<y<\frac RA\}\subset \Omega_A\cap\{1<r<R\}\subset\Omega_A\cap\{\frac 1A<y<2R\}\,,
$$
so instead of one identity, we write two inequalities and conclude that $\log R\int_{\omega_A}d\varphi\,d\psi$ is squeezed between $\log\frac{R}{2A}$ times $2\int_1^{\sqrt 2+1}\left(\int_{E(t,A)}\frac{ds}{s}\right)\frac{dt}t$ and $\log(2AR)$ times the same quantity, where we put $x=ty, z=sy$ and defined $E(t,A)$ to be the set of $s$ for which the triangle with the sides $1,t,s$ is admissible.
Now, dividing by $\log R$, letting $R\to+\infty$ and using the squeeze theorem, we conclude that
$$
\int_{\omega_A}d\varphi\,d\psi=
2\int_1^{\sqrt 2+1}\left(\int_{E(t,A)}\frac{ds}{s}\right)\frac{dt}t
$$
for every fixed $A$. But when $A\to+\infty$, the set $\omega_A$ expands to $\omega$ and for each $t$, the set $E(t,A)$ expands to $[t-1,1+\frac 1t]$, so the monotone convergence theorem finishes the story.
That's it. I tried to find a simple change of variables that would avoid using non-trivial identities for $\mathrm{Li}_2$ to get the final $\frac{\pi^2}8$ answer, but failed so far. Still, we have the result, so, I hope, somebody will eventually provide a simpler proof. The value $\frac 12$ of the probability is too nice to be there without a clear reason. :-)

@IosifPinelis Formally yes, but what's the difference between saying that the probability of an event is $1/2$ and saying that the probability of the complementary event is $1/2$? The one I chose resulted in the integration over a finite length interval in $t$, which was a bit more convenient, but if you choose the other one, you get pretty much the same type of integral via exactly the same argument in the end :-)

Very nice. See my response (in particular its "Added" section) for a self-contained proof that the $t$-integral equals $\pi^2/8$.

The variable $r$ (and the complications around it) can be eliminated from your method. Namely, if we define $t:=x/y=\sin(\phi)/\sin(\psi)$ and $s:=z/y=\sin(\phi-\psi)/\sin(\psi)$, then $dsdt/(st)=d\phi d\psi$. In other words, the Jacobian of the mapping $(\phi,\psi)\mapsto(\log(s),\log(t))$ is $\pm 1$, which is straightforward to verify.

@GHfromMO You are absolutely correct. I noticed that too after posting but decided not to change anything. The reason is that I preferred to keep the symmetry between $x,y,z$ as long as possible. In this particular problem it doesn't really matter in which order to integrate in the final formula, but sometimes it may be beneficial to postpone this decision until the very end. :-)

I see. I am trying to write a short note (mainly for myself) with two applications of your method, based on https://mathoverflow.net/q/469729 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/470028. Without $r$, I can simply say "by a change of variable of $(\phi,\psi)\mapsto(s,t)$", i.e. apply calculus without much thinking. Of course this change of variable is ingenious (thanks to you), but once it is given (with $s$ and $t$ being appropriate ratios formed from $a$, $b$, $c$), things are straightforward.

I have updated my responses at https://mathoverflow.net/q/469729 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/470028 accordingly. Check them out!

@fedja Hello, I had a similar idea to what GH has mentioned above: To write a paper on triangle inequality and its application in the field of machine learning (the motivation is explained here https://shorturl.at/fuAH7). I asked GH and he is happy to co-author. We be very happy if you could join us. Do let us know.

@NilotpalKantiSinha Ah, yes, sorry for the delay. The answer to the co-authorship offer is negative, but if you want to discuss some related stuff with me, you are welcome to do it any time :-)

Hi @fedja Well noted, no problem. Would it be OK if we mentioned you in the credits for the method? Also will definitely connect with you for related problems.

$\newcommand{\li}{\operatorname{Li}_2}$The following expression of the area (say $A$) was proposed in fedja's comment:
\begin{equation*}
    A=I:=\int_1^{1+\sqrt2}\frac{dt}t\,\ln\frac{t+1}{t(t-1)}. \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
It was noted in the comment by GH from MO that Mathematica evaluates the integral $I$ as
\begin{equation*}
    B:=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\frac12\,\ln(1+\sqrt2)^2+\li(1-\sqrt2)-\li(\sqrt2-1). \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
GH from MO also noted that, according to Lima,
\begin{equation*}
    B=\frac{\pi^2}{8}. 
\end{equation*}
The purpose of this answer is to provide a simple "human" proof of the Mathematica evaluation that
\begin{equation*}
    I=B. \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
Toward this end, write
\begin{equation*}
    I=I_1-I_2, \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    I_1:=\int_1^{1+\sqrt2}\frac{dt}t\,\ln\frac{t+1}{t},\quad 
    I_2:=\int_1^{1+\sqrt2}\frac{dt}t\,\ln(t-1). 
\end{equation*}
Next,
\begin{align*}
    I_1&=\int_1^{1+\sqrt2}\frac{dt}t\,\ln(1+1/t)    \\ 
    &=\int_1^{1+\sqrt2}\frac{dt}t\,\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\,t^{-k} \\ 
    &=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\int_1^{1+\sqrt2} dt\,t^{-k-1} \\ 
    &=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2}\,(1-(\sqrt2-1)^k) \\ 
    &=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2}+\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{(1-\sqrt2)^k}{k^2} \\ 
    &=\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\li(1-\sqrt2). \tag{50}\label{50} 
\end{align*}
Somewhat similarly,
\begin{align*}
    I_2&=\int_{\sqrt2-1}^1\frac{du}u\,\ln(1/u-1)    \\ 
& =\int_{\sqrt2-1}^1\frac{du}u\,\ln(1-u)-\int_{\sqrt2-1}^1\frac{du}u\,\ln u \\ 
& =-\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{k}\,\int_{\sqrt2-1}^1 du\,u^{k-1}+\frac12\ln(\sqrt2-1)^2 \\ 
& =-\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{k^2}\,(1-(\sqrt2-1)^k)+\frac12\ln(\sqrt2-1)^2 \\ 
& =-\frac{\pi^2}6+\li(\sqrt2-1)+\frac12\ln(\sqrt2-1)^2. \tag{60}\label{60}
\end{align*}
Now \eqref{30} follows immediately from \eqref{40}, \eqref{50}, and \eqref{60}. $\quad\Box$

Using the book Lewin: Polylogarithms and associated functions (Elsevier, 1981) as a reference, we can give a streamlined proof of the identity
$$I:=\int_1^{\sqrt 2+1}\log\left(\frac{t+1}{t(t-1)}\right)\frac{dt}{t}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}.$$
In the "Added" section, I will make this proof self-contained without any reference to the book.
By a change of variable $t=1/x$, we see that
$$I=\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1\log\left(\frac{x(1+x)}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}.$$
It is also clear that
$$I_1:=\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1\log(x)\frac{dx}{x}=\left[\frac{\log^2(x)}{2}\right]_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1=-\frac{\log^2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{2}.$$
On the other hand, by (1.66) of the book,
$$I_2:=\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=2\chi_2(1)-2\chi_2(\sqrt{2}-1).$$
Now it is classical that
$$\chi_2(1)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8},$$
while (1.68) of the book tells us that
$$\chi_2(\sqrt{2}-1)=\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac{\log^2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{4}.$$
Putting everything together,
$$I=I_1+I_2=-\frac{\log^2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{4}-2\left(\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac{\log^2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{8}.$$
I should add that (1.66) follows immediately from the definition of $\chi_2$, while (1.68) takes a few lines to prove. Both were known to Euler and Legendre.
Added. We can make the calculation of $I_2$ (and hence $I$) self-contained as follows. The key point is the identity
$$\int_y^1\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}-\int_0^\frac{1-y}{1+y}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=\log(y)\log\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right),\qquad y\in(0,1).$$
Indeed, the $y$-derivatives of the two sides are the same, while both sides tend to zero as $y\to 0+$ or $y\to 1-$. Plugging $y:=\sqrt{2}-1$ into this identity, we infer that
$$\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}-\int_0^{\sqrt{2}-1}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=\log^2(\sqrt{2}-1).\tag{1}$$
On the other hand,
$$\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}+\int_0^{\sqrt{2}-1}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{\pi^2}{4},\tag{2}$$
as follows readily from
$$\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1},\qquad x\in(0,1).$$
Averaging $(1)$ and $(2)$, we infer that
$$I_2=\frac{\log^2(\sqrt{2}-1)}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{8},$$
and then
$$I=I_1+I_2=\frac{\pi^2}{8}.$$

An approach bypassing polylogarithms is as follows:
\begin{align}\int_1^{1+\sqrt2}\log\frac{t+1}{t(t-1)}\frac{dt}t&\stackrel{ibp}=\int_1^{1+\sqrt2}\frac{t^2+2t-1}{t(t^2-1)}\log t\,dt\\&\stackrel{t=e^u}=\int_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}1}\frac{\sinh u+1}{\sinh u}u\,du\\&\stackrel{v=\sinh u}=\frac12\operatorname{arsinh}^21+\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{arsinh}v}{v\sqrt{1+v^2}}\,dv\\&=\frac{\pi^2}8\end{align} as shown here. This is directly related to the Legendre chi function at $\nu=2$.

What do you mean by $ibp$ and why does the corresponding equality hold?

@IosifPinelis Integration by parts, and $\log((t+1)/(t(t-1)))\log t$ is zero at the endpoints

The two substitutions can be combined by using $t=v+\sqrt{1+v^2}$, which is the appropriate branch of $v=\sinh u=\sinh(\ln t)=(t-1/t)/2$.

This is an attempt to work directly with the equation $\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}=\frac{\sin x+\sin y}{\sin(x+y)}$ from the question. As $\cos x$ is injective on $[0,\pi]$, it might be sensible to try to express the area in terms of $\cos x$. To this end, we compute the algebraic relation between $a:=\cos x$ and $b:=\cos y$. Using the addition theorem for $\sin(x+y)$ and eliminating $\sin x$ and $\sin y$ via $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$, we arrive at
\begin{equation}
(a-b)(a+b)^2 + 2(1-a^2)(1-b^2)=0.
\end{equation}
The $(a,b)$-curve given by this equation admits a rational parametrization:
\begin{align*}
a(t) &= \frac{t^3 + t^2 + t - 1}{2t^2}\\
b(t) &= \frac{t^3 + t^2 - t + 1}{2t}
\end{align*}
The area we are looking for is
\begin{equation}
I=\int_{0}^\pi y\,dx=\int_{0}^\pi\arccos(\cos y)\,dx.
\end{equation}
If $x$ runs from $0$ to $\pi$, then $a=\cos x$ runs from $1$ down to $-1$, and this is achieved if $t$ runs from $1$ down to $\sqrt{2}-1$.
From $a(t)=\cos x$ we get $a'(t)=-\sin x\frac{dx}{dt}=-\sqrt{1-a(t)^2}\frac{dx}{dt}$, hence
\begin{equation}
I=\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1\frac{a'(t)}{\sqrt{1-a(t)^2}}\arccos b(t)\,dt.
\end{equation}
There are several possibilities to continue from there (see my and @Zacky's comments to the OP's question). For instance, using
\begin{equation}
\arccos b=2\arctan\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{1+b}=2\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{1+b}}\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz=2\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1-b^2}}{1+b+(1-b)s^2}ds
\end{equation}
and $1-b(t)^2=t\cdot(1-a(t)^2)$ we get
\begin{equation}
I=2\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1\int_0^1\frac{ta'(t)}{1+b(t)+(1-b(t))s^2}ds\,dt.
\end{equation}
Written out explicitly this is
\begin{equation}
I=2\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^1\int_0^1\frac{t^3 - t + 2}{(1-s^2)t(t^3 + t^2 + \frac{1+3s^2}{1-s^2}t + 1)}ds\,dt.
\end{equation}
It is tempting to switch the order of integration and first integrate along $t$ by a partial fraction decomposition. The problem is that the roots of the cubic in the denominator are non-constant algebraic functions in $s$. On the other hand, the simple answer of the finite result should allow for some simple trick here ?!?
