Generalization of the triangle inequality to complex exponents: What is $P\left(\left| x^{a+bi} + y^{a+bi} \right| \ge \left|z^{a+bi}\right|\right)$?
Let $x \le y \le z$ be the length of the sides of a triangle whose vertices are uniformly random on the circumference of a circle. In this question, it was proved that if $a \ge 1$, then the probability
$$
P\left(x^a + y^a \ge z^a\right) = \frac{1}{a^2}
$$
This is a followup / generalization to this question to complex exponents. Let $a+bi$ be a complex number, $a \ge 1, b \ge 0$. What is the probability
$$
P\left(\left| x^{a+bi} + y^{a+bi} \right| \ge \left|z^{a+bi}\right|\right).
$$
Experimental data show that if $b > 0$ then $\displaystyle P\left(\left| x^{a+bi} + y^{a+bi} \right| \ge \left|z^{a+bi}\right |\right) < \frac{1}{a^2}$ and as $b \to \infty$ the probability converges to a which depends only on $a$.

It is clear that $P\left(\left| x^{a+bi} + y^{a+bi} \right| \ge \left|z^{a+bi}\right|\right)$ is less than $P\left(x^a + y^a \ge z^a\right) = \frac{1}{a^2}$ for $b>0$, because $x^a + y^a>\left| x^{a+bi} + y^{a+bi} \right|$ outside a measure zero set for $b>0$, and $\left|z^{a+bi}\right |=z^a$ for all $b\in\mathbb{R}$.
